# Implement binary threshold on my own using python but getting wrong result

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-detection, threshold

I am trying to implemnt the binary threshold on my own using python, First I have converted the image to to gray scale image. Then I have taken the max value of the gay scale image and threat that value as the threshold value. Then I put nested for loop to carry out that the condition checking. below is my code. I have taken the example Image used ion openCV website. [image: threshold]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as im



img = im.imread('threshold.png')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

R=img[:,:,0]
G=img[:,:,1]
B=img[:,:,2]


M,N=R.shape

gray_img= np.zeros((M,N))
intensity= np.zeros((M,N))

for i in range(M):
        for j in range(N):
            gray_img[i, j]=(R[i, j]*0.2989)+(G[i, j]*0.5870)+(B[i, j]*0.114);

t=gray_img.max()


for i in range(1, M-1):
    for j in range(1,N-1):
        intensity[i,j]=gray_img[i,j]
        if(intensity[i,j]>t):
            intensity[i,j]=1
        else:
            intensity[i,j]=0
    
    
plt.imshow(intensity)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic, I am hoping to make you realise something. How many pixels do you expect to be brighter than the brightest pixel?

Comment: I don’t see the problem. You say you get the wrong result. What do you expect to get?

Comment: Try t>0.5 (mid gray). That should give half black and half white.

Comment: See I am new to image processing domain. I am learning now. I am trying to code what I have understood is correct. Seems like my understanding is not complete regarding threshold